# Failed to set up deployment: Repository UpdateSiteSourceControl operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I am trying to connect my Azure App services to Azure DevOps repository I am getting the following error, any guidance or resolutions

```
Failed to set up deployment: Repository UpdateSiteSourceControl operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.SourceControls.OauthException: Vso AddWebHook: 
Failed because you are not an administrator on the VSTS project.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is clear, you need administrator right in the Azure DevOps

Comment: Thanks, the issue was fixed after changing the user to administrator in DevOps